# What is the difference between c# and visual c#?

Tags: c#

I am an intermediate Java programmer and want to shift to C#. I am totally new to this Microsoft language. In books, they are using both terms Visual C# and C#. Can anyone please tell the real difference between the terms?

Comment: I see some evidence for "Visual C#" as Microsoft's implementation of the C# language. Not seen much support for that in the field, though, where usage is pretty much interchangeable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Visual C# is an implementation of the C# language by Microsoft.

Visual C# is just C#. You can build any kind of .NET application using C# and Visual Studio makes it easier test and debug your application.
for example using Visual Studio brings you lots of capabilities :

1. Code Editor
2. Debugger
3. Designer
4. Windows Forms Designer
5. WPF Designer

   ,...

for more information about Visual Studio read this page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio

**Update**: Visual C# is the marketing name that Microsoft uses for C#, So nobody calls it Visual C#.

Comment: "Visual C# is just a GUI designed by Microsoft" That's Visual Studio.

Answer (score 13):

C# would refer to the language itself, which can be compiled without the Visual Studio environment using the .NET SDK & the supplied csc.exe (c# compiler - like javac) or the Mono environment.

Visual C# likely refers to the C# language **AND** the Visual Studio IDE / Toolchain (SQL/Reports etc.).

Answer (score 11):

There is no real difference between C# and Visual C#. The terms are often used interchangeably.

Visual C# kind of implies using the Visual Studio for C# development. But there is only C#.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh341490.aspx) for learning resources.